# Finding out the common / uncommon elements between two Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Consider I have two arrays:

```
$friends = Array('foo', 'bar', 'alpha');
$attendees = Array('foo', 'bar');
```

Now I need to populate a new array `$nonattendees` which contains only the elements which are in `$friends` array and **not** in `$attendees` array. i.e, `$nonattendees` array should be populated with 'alpha'.

Is there any in built array operation available in **PHP** to achieve the above functionality or should I write my own `for` loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) seems to be what you're looking for.

```
$nonattendees = array_diff($friends, $attendees);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// differancee items code 
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);

// common items code //

$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php has plenty of functions for you.
array_intersect() or array_diff() for example

Manual pages are always better choice for such a direct questions.