# How to find common elements in two arrays?

Tags: php

There are two arrays. It is necessary to display a list from the first array on the page, in which the elements of the second array will be highlighted, for example with a color. Probably it is necessary to read one array in a loop and compare, for example preg_match with the second array and if there is a coincidence - to allocate. Does anyone have a more beautiful solution?

Comment: You should post your question in English so you will reach a bigger audience here. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out the common / uncommon elements between two Arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590458/finding-out-the-common-uncommon-elements-between-two-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function that does pretty much what you need. If you want to compare the elements using regular expressions, try [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php), but you will need to prepare the pattern first.